# Returning interface without concrete class

Tags: .net, interface

I came across a  post that said when returning an interface, one should not return the concrete class implementing it because it makes programmers using the function that returns the interface assume things according to what they see returns. It may cause code to work now but on later versions may not.
So finally to the question. Is there a way to seperate the interface  return type from the concrete class implementing it? Can I return an interface without further metadata that comes from the concrete and that will be available to others?
Thanks

Comment: You can always _simply_ return an interface (of course assuming this is what you want). Caller will be always able to _see_ concrete class but it won't be part of your _contract_. They may cast to concrete class (if public), use Reflection if it's a private type but...well it's an _explicit_ action, they violated contract and they rely on an implementation detail. In short: it's their fault and their business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *declaration* of the reference you return should always be the interface type, not the concrete class that implements it.  Such a class normally is declared *internal* so nobody can monkey with it and you're free the change its implementation as you see fit without breaking any client code.

At runtime, the client programmer is however **always** going to be able see which class actually implements the interface.  And can peek at the private parts.  You cannot stop this, the debugger is smart enough to figure it out.  That's what debuggers do.  This is of no concern, the view the debugger provides does not mean that the client programmer can freely party on your class.  Accessibility is still enforced at compile time.  But if he's trying to catch the plane heading home and you're not picking up the phone, then yes, he may well use Reflection to poke himself out of trouble.   That you'll break that Q&D hack with your next release is not something that will surprise him :)